# Base 16 conversion

Tags: radix

I have AB in base 16 and want to convert that to base 8.

A base 16 = 12 base 8
B base 16 = 13 base 8

we have ...

**AB** *base 16* = **12** *base 8* x **20^1** base 8 + **13** base 8 x **20^0** *base 8* = **253** *base 8*

and now

Can someone explain where the hell 20 comes out from the base conversion?????

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is discussed in detail on math.stackexchange.com (and the basic algorithm for base conversion is given as well): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313954/number-base-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the 20 comes from: `10` in base 16 = `16` in base 10 = `20` in base 8

So the calculation can be thought of as: `AB` in base 16 = `A * 10^1 + B * 10^0` in base 16 = `12 * 20^1 + 13 * 20^0` in base 8 = `240 + 13` in base 8 = `253` in base 8

Comment: Oh, is converting the 16 in base 10 to base 8... Thanks so much!